# c# protected key word related problem

Tags: c#

I have a product.aspx class

```
public partial class _Products : Product
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.m1(); ///here I am facing problem y intelligence system not allowing me access the product class method m1();   
    }
   new virtual int m1() 
    {
        return 10;   
    }
}
```

and in my AppCode I have a class product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    protected void m1() 
    { 

    }
    public void m2() 
    { 

    }
```

Tthe problem is, p1.m1(); here I am facing problem my intelligence system not allowing me access the product class method m1();

Comment: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/why-can-t-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instantiate a new Product you cannot access it's protected member from another class, even if it derives from Product

Comment: thats what i want to know, y so?

Comment: but protected are available in sub class y cant i access that protected method?

Comment: u have understood me absolutely right, i want to know y is not that possible?

Comment: Protected means that you can call the Method via 'this.' or 'base.' from a derived class, however you cannot call it on another instance of the class - regardless.

Comment: why can't we call protected method on an object, is it behave like the static?

Comment: @Novice - that is actually a complex question. Eric Lippert has a blog post on it, IIRC.

Comment: Ok sir i go through the post, well thanks for your help, i understood most now

Answer (score 2):

You don't state he problem, but I expect you mean:

(base-class)

```
protected abstract int m1();
```

(sub-class)

```
protected override int m1() {
    return 10;
}
```

Also; your page **is** a product; you shouldn't need to create an *additional* product in the constructor. So Page_Load should probably be invoking virtual mehods on the current instance ("this").

Comment: i am just confuse that y the base class protected method m1() can't be accessed in sub class using the base class object?

Answer (score 1):

m1() method in Product (parent) class returns void but m1() method in _Products (child) class returns int. They should return the same type. Also you probably want to use virtual key word for m1() method in the parent class and use override (or new) keyword for m1() method in the child class.

Answer (score 1):

only private methods can onot be called from subclass , protected method can be called from the subclass BUT if you create the instance of the class where protected method defind , you woun't be able to get the protected method

try below  example

```
 public class P : Product
{
    public P()
    {
        m1();
    }
}


public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {        //        // TODO: Add constructor logic here        
    }
    protected void m1() { }
    public void m2() { }



}
```

Comment: ok, now i understand the nature of protected that, a protected can not be call on an object but y so?

Comment: because you don't want let the user of your class directly call this method , you may have very sensitive code written in this method do you want your user to call that code ? i hope no but you want the same code should not be repeated all in your sub-classed so you let your subclass call this protected method

Comment: - "because you don't want let the user of your class directly call this method" i am not getting your this point after all user of that call will call that method in any way, like base.methodName();